# Binding a Color Resource?

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, colors, wpf-controls

I have an odd problem that's got me stumped. I am modifying the WPF Calendar control template, and for reasons that I explain below, I have to use a `Color` resource, rather than a `SolidColorBrush` resource, for my text color. Right now, my `Color` resource looks like this:

```
<!-- My Colors -->
<Color x:Key="MyTextColor">Blue</Color>
```

Now I want to bind the `Color` resource to a parent property, but the `Color` object doesn't have a `Binding` property. So, how would I go about binding this resource? Thanks for your help.

---

***Note on why I have to use a Color resource:*** The WPF Calendar control animates its text for mouse-overs in several places, and each animation uses a named `SolidColorBrush`. I can't replace the brushes with a resource reference, since I want to preserve the animations, which means I have to preserve the name. But I can replace the brush colors, as I did in this brush named *TextColor*:

```
<!-- Modification: Changed template brush color -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="TextColor">
    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyTextColor" />
    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
</SolidColorBrush>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem in our software and came up with this solution. Basically you create a class that implements an extension to the static resource class of WPF which handles binding and then consume it on your XAML code. Pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

I have selected smoura's answer as being the correct one, because it does answer the question that I had asked. However, I think I may have asked the wrong question, and therein lies a better solution to the problem.

I decided I was off course in using a resource, and then trying to bind that resource. A much better approach is to simply bind the `Color` property directly. To do that, I created a simple `IValueConverter` called `BrushToColorConverter`, then used that to bind the named brush's color to the `Foreground` property of the `UserControl` that I am creating. The markup looks like this:

```
<!-- Modification: Changed template brush color -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="TextColor" Color="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Converter={StaticResource BrushToColorConverter}}" />
```

This approach completely eliminates the `Color` resource that I had used previously. It is simpler and, I suspect, more efficient.